# GWT - [ERROR] Line 265: Failed to resolve 'org.AwardTracker.client.RichTextToolbar.Strings' via deferred binding

Tags: java, gwt

I am using the GWT showcase:

http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRichText

and google-web-toolkit:

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/text/RichTextToolbar.java

to create a rich text area to enter and display to. The issue I have is that when I compile I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'org/AwardTracker/client/RichTextToolbar.java'
  [ERROR] Line 265: Failed to resolve 'org.AwardTracker.client.RichTextToolbar.Strings' via deferred binding
```

Line 265 is:

```
private Strings strings = (Strings) GWT.create(Strings.class);
```

I am including this in a project that works and is using String in other classes. Such as:

```
String imagePath = new String();
```

I only have a basic understanding of GWT and java so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

After adding RichTextToolbar_Strings.properties

I get the following compile error:

```
Compiling module org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker
   Validating units:
      Ignored 2 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.AwardTracker.client.RichTextToolbar.Strings'
      Rebinding org.AwardTracker.client.RichTextToolbar.Strings
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.LocalizableGenerator
            Processing interface org.AwardTracker.client.RichTextToolbar.Strings
               Generating method body for black()
                  [ERROR] No resource found for key 'black'
com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractResource$MissingResourceException: No resource found for key 'black'
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractResource$ResourceList.getRequiredStringExt(AbstractResource.java:290)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.SimpleValueMethodCreator.createMethodFor(SimpleValueMethodCreator.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractLocalizableImplCreator.delegateToCreator(AbstractLocalizableImplCreator.java:501)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.ConstantsImplCreator.emitMethodBody(ConstantsImplCreator.java:163)
    at com.google.gwt.user.rebind.AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.genMethod(AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.java:277)
    at com.google.gwt.user.rebind.AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.emitMethods(AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.java:239)
    at com.google.gwt.user.rebind.AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.emitClass(AbstractGeneratorClassCreator.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractLocalizableImplCreator.generateConstantOrMessageClass(AbstractLocalizableImplCreator.java:221)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.LocalizableGenerator.generate(LocalizableGenerator.java:151)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.LocalizableGenerator.generate(LocalizableGenerator.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:676)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleGwtCreate(UnifyAst.java:387)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:255)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:244)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:117)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:65)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:117)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:65)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:117)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:138)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:134)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:449)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:940)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:665)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:34)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:271)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:223)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:139)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:99)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:106)
                  [WARN] Searched the following resources:
                     [WARN] org/AwardTracker/client/RichTextToolbar_Strings.properties
                        List of keys found
                           </style>
                           white-space
                           <span
                           <!--[if
                           .cursor,
                           tr.inline_comment
                           {"loggedInUserEmail"
                           background-color
                           </span>
                           genState.table_base_id
                           changed_paths.push('/tags/2.4.0');
                           <style
                           <img
                           height
                           </td>
                           element
                           kibbles.skipper.addStopListener(
                           margin
                           <table><tr><td>Go
                           <dt>svn
                           onclick
                           numRow
                           </tr></table>
                           <br>
                           .nocursor,
                           CR_BrowseIntegrationFactory);
                           srcGenState.chunk_id
                           >
                           alignerRunning
                           genState.row_num
                           row.className
                           google-web-toolkit
                           </tr>
                           itemscope
                           srcGenState.row_num
                           <pre>Tag
                           by
                           .menuIcon.on
                           #review_nav
                           <![endif]-->
                           setTimeout(continueToSetLineNumberHeights,
                           element.className
                           35
                           window.location
                           div.draft
                           <option
                           return;
                           setTimeout(setLineNumberHeights,
                           reloadCursors();
                           Your
                           </html>
                           })();
                           |
                           }
                           <form
                           #file_flipper
                           border-top
                           RichTextToolBar_Strings.properties
                           'u',
                           ><tr>
                           codereviews.registerActivityListener(CR_ActivityType.REVEAL_DRAFT_PLATE,
                           </body>
                           .menuIcon.down
                           <!DOCTYPE
                           ...</pre>
                           numsGenState.chunk_id
                           ><tr
                           <body
                           #file_flipper.hidden
                           </a>
                           changed_urls.push('/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0?rx3d10590x26specx3dsvn11688');
                           contributes
                           kibbles.skipper.addRevKey("p");
                           ><u>Sign
                           ><td
                           continueToSetLineNumberHeights();
                           kibbles.skipper.setCurrentStop(lastStop);
                           codereviews.registerActivityListener(CR_ActivityType.DISCARD_DRAFT_COMMENT,
                           lastStop
                           page
                           genState.row_num++;
                           ><u><b>glyndwr.bartlett@gmail.com</b></u>
                           rowsInThisPass++;
                           prev.element.className
                           </pre>
                           for
                           <div
                           <pre><table
                           title
                           margin-left
                           kibbles.keys.addKeyPressListener(
                           ['siteTracker._setAccount',
                           </head>
                           ></table></pre>
                           font-family
                           class
                           ['siteTracker._trackPageview']);
                           s.parentNode.insertBefore(po,
                           </title>
                           .undermouse
                           <dd>native</dd>
                           <dl>
                           vertical-align
                           </div>
                           border-bottom
                           <div>Size
                           max-width
                           {var
                           <pre
                           avoid
                           (function()
                           kibbles.skipper.append(element);
                           numsGenState.table
                           </dl>
                           window.___gcfg
                           codereviews.registerActivityListener(CR_ActivityType.REVEAL_PUB_PLATE,
                           kibbles.skipper.LISTENER_TYPE.PRE,
                           <strong
                           window.onload
                           >/tags/2.4.0</option>
                           href
                           id
                           if
                           var
                           srcGenState.table
                           po.type
                           .menuIcon.off
                           kibbles.skipper.reset();
                           </script>
                           <p>File
                           div.published
                           kibbles.keys.addKeyPressListener('j',
                           'r',
                           kibbles.keys.addKeyPressListener('k',
                           startOver
                           genState.table
                           genState.chunk_id++;
                           <input
                           </ul>
                           oldTR.className
                           (document.getElementsByTagName('head')
                           </td></tr></table>
                           cellpadding
                           gutterOut();
                           <title>RichTextToolbar_Strings.properties
                           word-wrap
                           _gaq.push(
                           <html>
                           GWT
                           display
                           lineNumUnderMouse
                           <div>
                           .list
                           width
                           margin-bottom
                           return
                           newTR.className
                           'gr_svn11688_'
                           while
                           numsGenState.row_num
                           updateCursorForCell(data.cellId,
                           <li><a
                           window.onresize
                           RichTextToolbar$Strings.properties
                           next.element.className
                           <span>
                           numRow.firstChild.style.height
                           ><u>Profile</u></a>
                           function
                           background-image
                           </form>
                           border
                           <a
                           </select>
                           alt
                           div.draft,
                           initLineNumberHeights();
                           <td
                           CR_toggleCommentDisplay();
                           kibbles.skipper.setOption('padding_bottom',
                           <link
                           background
                           <tr
                           kibbles.skipper.setOption('padding_top',
                           <meta
                           font-size
                           <select
                           <p>Change
                           <ul
                           <tr>
                           margin-top
                           <script
                           on
                           ga.src
                           //
                           padding
                           <table
                           </table>
                           padding-top
                           ><u>My
                           srcRow
                           codereviews
                           <head>
                           <dd>text/plain;
                           &nbsp;
                           <p>Older
                           kibbles.skipper.addFwdKey("n");
                           <div><a
                           loadCursors();
   [ERROR] Errors in 'org/AwardTracker/client/RichTextToolbar.java'
      [ERROR] Line 265: Failed to resolve 'org.AwardTracker.client.RichTextToolbar.Strings' via deferred binding
   [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
      [WARN] org.AwardTracker.client.RichTextToolbar_Strings_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Strings` != `String`. Your example `new String()` is a creation of a new String value. `Strings` is something different. In short it will bind text from property file with the `Strings` interface due to the fact it extends `Constants`. See the GWT documentation about how this works for a more elaborate explanation.  http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nConstants.html
In this case your should also have the file `RichTextToolbar_Strings.properties` from the demo in the same folder as the `RichTextToolbar.java` file. I think the problem is caused by this missing file. Do you have it?

Comment: Hi Hilbrand, Thanks for your help. I went back to the sample and saved the required file into my project in the same folder as the RichTextToolbar.java file. However, it saved as .htm instead of .properties so I renamed it. I did get a warning when I did this. Now when I compile I get the error above (I edited my original post). Once again thanks for your help. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Hi Hilbrand, On further investigation I found that when I saved the file it from the original project it brought with it some html. So I deleted all the contents from the version in my project and did a cut and past of the data displayed in their project when you open the file. It now works. Thank you very much for your help, it is greatly appreciated. Regards, Glyn